# Is there a window style that corresponds to a HWND's class menu?

Tags: windows, winapi, hwnd, window-style

Windows has a number of window styles that corresponds to attributes of a window, and `SetWindowLongPtr`, used with parameters `GWL_EXSTYLE` or `GWL_STYLE`, can be used to toggle these attributes ON/OFF. For example, `WS_CAPTION` can be used to toggle a window's title bar ON/OFF. I was wondering if there's a window style that corresponds to toggling the [class menu](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633574(v=vs.85).aspx#class_menu) of a HWND ON/OFF as well.

Note: I understand that the class menu can be toggled via the `SetMenu` APIs, but was just curious if there's a corresponding window style as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no **window** style, but there is a **class** value instead.

When a window class is registered via [`RegisterClass()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633586.aspx)/[`RegisterClassEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633587.aspx), the [`WNDCLASS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633576.aspx)/[`WNDCLASSEX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633577.aspx) structure has an `lpszMenuName` member:

> lpszMenuName
>   Type: LPCTSTR
>
> The resource name of the class menu, as the name appears in the resource file. If you use an integer to identify the menu, use the MAKEINTRESOURCE macro. If this member is NULL, windows belonging to this class have no default menu.

You can use [`SetClassLong()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633588.aspx)/[`SetClassLongPtr()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633589.aspx) with its `nIndex` parameter set to `GCLP_MENUNAME` to change the `lpszMenuName` value for the class used by a given window.

Comment: *You can use SetClassLong()/SetClassLongPtr() with its nIndex parameter set to GCLP_MENUNAME to change the lpszMenuName value for the class used by a given window.* - You can, but it won't have any effect on any given window. The class menu is only evaluated when creating a window.

Answer (score 1):

There is no style that corresponds to a window's menu. The class menu is toggled on and off by setting the `lpszMenuName` field of the [WNDCLASSEX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633577.aspx) structure to a valid menu resource name or `NULL`, if no class menu is requested.

Note that a window class is a template to create a window. You can override the menu entry in your call to [CreateWindowEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632680.aspx) when creating a window.